# Laravel Error: Missing required parameters

Tags: php, laravel

Please help me out. I'm having the missing required parameter's error. This is the form script:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <!--first column-->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 ">
            <!-- Default form contact -->

        <form class="text-center border border-light p-5" action="{{route('updating', $update->id)}}" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="POST">


            <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}" >
                    @method('PATCH')
                <div class="well">
                    <p class="h4 mb-4">Edit Updates</p>
                </div>
                <!-- Name -->
            <input type="text" name="title" id="defaultContactFormName" class="form-control mb-2" value=" {{ old('title') ?? $update->title }} ">
                <!-- Message -->
                <div class="form-group">
                    <textarea class="form-control rounded-0" name="body" id="exampleFormControlTextarea2" rows="5" value="{{ old('title') ?? $update->body }}"></textarea>
                </div>
                <!-- Send button -->
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Publish</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And this is my controller and edit function:

```
public function update(Request $request, $title)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required'
    ]);

    //Publishing Updates

    $update = Update::findOrFail($title);
    $update->title = $request->input('title');
    $update->body = $request->input('body');
    $update->save();

    return redirect('admin.updates')->with('success', 'Saved');
}
```

And this is my route:

```
 Route::patch('/updates/{title}/update', 'UpdatesController@update')->name('updating');
```

I keep getting the error and i don't know where its coming from.

Comment: Can you post the rest of the form? Do you have an input with name "title" and input with name "body"?

Comment: Hi, please add the full error message.

Comment: Please checkout this form action area which correct or not ```{{route('updating', [ $update->id, $update])}}```

Comment: The route should simply be `route('updating', $update->id)`, if `id` is the primary key on that table.